# loop within a loop for updating db record

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a deals table with the following data:

```
dealID   |   date    |   followUP  |  user
1        |2012-10-15 |    Yes      |
2        |2012-12-24 |    Yes      |
3        |2013-01-05 |             |
4        |2013-02-02 |    Yes      |
5        |2013-02-02 |    Yes      |
```

And a users table with my users list

```
userID    | name
1         | john
2         | eric
3         | anne
```

What I would like to do is to query the first table that has followUP set as 'YES' then from the result assign a user to them in sequence from the users table so my final deals table will look like this

```
dealID   |   date    |   followUP  | userID
1        |2012-10-15 |    Yes      | 1
2        |2012-12-24 |    Yes      | 2
3        |2013-01-05 |             |
4        |2013-02-02 |    Yes      | 3
5        |2013-02-02 |    Yes      | 1
```

I know its a loop but for some reason i cant figure out how to setup the second loop to assign the value of the users. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How will you decide which user will be assigned to which deal? You do not have any userids in deals table ?

Comment: You want to *assign* a user to the deals that have `followUP = 'Yes'` in sequential order based on the `userID`?

Comment: for now just assign the userID in sequence to the users table. So far the only thing ive been able to do is update the deals table but only for one user, I cant figure out how to loop the userID while the deals update query is looping as well.

Comment: So, your `userID` in the "user" table is not auto incremental??

Comment: my IDs are all AI. Yes, I would like to update the deals table that has followUP = 'Yes' in sequential order based on the userID

Comment: So in sequential order means if a deal has follow-up = YES, then you will pickup the first user id which does not appear in the deals table and put it there. This does not make sense. There should be some way to decide which user owns which deal?

Comment: There really is no other criteria I am simply dividing and updating the result of the deals query to a list of users. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get your user IDs into an array so it looks:

```
$uids = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Then, when reading the records from deals table compose update queries like so:

```
$follow_up_user_idx = 0;
$update_queries = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // ... do whatever you need to
    if($row['followUP'] != 'Yes') continue;
    $update_queries[] = "UPDATE `deals` SET `user` = '" . $uids[$follow_up_user_idx] . "'
                         WHERE `dealID` = '" . $row['dealID'] . "' LIMIT 1";
    $follow_up_user_idx++;
    if($follow_up_user_idx > count($uids) - 1) $follow_up_user_idx = 0;
}
```

Now you have all update queries. Just execute them:

```
foreach($update_queries as $uq) {
    mysqli_query($link, $uq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to follow a series of steps to achieve what you have mentioned.

1) Fetch all the records from database where `followUP` is 'Yes'.
Lets say that first table is `deals`. So, fetch all records where `followUP` is 'Yes'.
Lets say, you have result in $deals_details.

2) Fetch all the users(name) from database.
Lets say that second table is `users`. So, fetch all users.
Lets say, you have all users' names in $users_details array.
Get a count of total users in system in seperate variable say $users_count.

3) Loop through $deals_details and assign each user one-by-one sequentially from $users_details.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($deals_details as $keyDD => $valueDD){
    $user = $users_details[$i];
    $i++;
    if($i == $users_count)
        $i = 0;
    $query = "update `deals` set user = '".$user."' where dealID = '".$valueDD['dealID']."'";

    //fire query
    //$link is connection variable.
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Table user
+---------------+---------------+------------+
|    user_id    |   username    | user_level |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
|      1        |  superadmin   |   admin    |
|      2        |  subadmin     |   admin    |
|      3        |  team1        |   team     |
|      4        |  team2        |   team     |
|      5        |  team3        |   team     |
|      6        |  customer1    |   customer |
|      7        |  customer2    |   customer |
|      8        |  customer3    |   customer |
|      9        |  customer4    |   customer |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
Table complaint:
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| complaint_id  |   complaint   |  user_id   |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
|      1        |  os issue     |      7     |
|      2        |  USB issue    |      8     |
|      3        |  OS currepted |      7     |
|      4        |  HD issue     |      9     |
|      5        |  DVD issue    |      6     |
|      6        |  SW problem   |      9     |
|      7        |  Network issue|      9     |
|      8        |  system issue |      6     |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
Table assign_work
+---------------+------------+
| complaint_id  |  user_id   |
+---------------+------------+
|      1        |      3     |
|      2        |      4     |
|      3        |      5     |
|      4        |      3     |
|      5        |      4     |
|      6        |      5     |
|      7        |      3     |
|      8        |      4     |
+---------------+------------+

When customer raise the complaint data should save in complaint table also that last 
complaint_id should save in assign_work table at the same time
 user_id also save sequencially, fetch from user table who are the team that person id only.
I m new in ph please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a poor design decision.  Without knowing more about your application, I'd be tempted to wait for a user to become available/request a deal, then assign to them (from a queue) the next deal requiring follow-up.  Even if you have good reasons to assign users before they are "available", you might consider doing so upon deal creation/modification based on some appropriate business logic (e.g. maintaining a queue of users to be assigned to the next deal).

Indeed, there's no particularly nice way of performing this operation with a simple `UPDATE` statement.  One way to accomplish it purely within the database would be to use a stored procedure (it's not especially concurrency-safe though, as changes to the `Users` table between closing and reopening the `_curUser` cursor may cause undesirable effects; one might instead copy the `Users` to a temporary table for the purposes of this procedure, depending on your desired logic):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE assignDeals() BEGIN
  DECLARE _userID, _dealID BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE _done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE _curUser CURSOR FOR
    SELECT   userID
    FROM     users
    ORDER BY userID;

  DECLARE _curDeal CURSOR FOR
    SELECT   dealID
    FROM     deals
    WHERE    followUP = 'Yes'
    ORDER BY dealID
    FOR UPDATE;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET _done := TRUE;

  PREPARE stmt FROM 'UPDATE deals SET userID = ? WHERE dealID = ?';

  OPEN _curUser;
  OPEN _curDeal;

  readDeal: LOOP
    FETCH _curDeal INTO _dealID;
    IF _done THEN
      LEAVE readDeal;
    END IF;

    FETCH _curUser INTO _userID;
    IF _done THEN
      SET _done := FALSE;
      CLOSE _curUser;
      OPEN  _curUser;
      FETCH _curUser INTO _userID;
      IF _done THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET
          MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No users';
        LEAVE readDeal;
      END IF;
    END IF;

    SET @userID := _userID, @dealID := _dealID;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @userID, @dealID;
  END LOOP readDeal;

  CLOSE _curUser;
  CLOSE _curDeal;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/869c9/1/1).